# S3AsyncClient - remove Authorization header

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am attempting to use S3AsyncClient to download an S3 object with a pre-signed URL. However, the request still goes out with an Authorization header, including a signature which is produced with a cipher that is not compatible with this particular S3 instance (this is an Enterprise S3 instance that emulates AWS S3 object storage). This results in an SSLException. The URL works when I send a request in browser or through Postman without Authorization header.

Can I send this sort of GET request with a pre-signed URL through S3AsyncClient without Authorization, x-amz-content-sha256, and X-Amz-Date Headers?

Log for presigned URL:

```
Generating pre-signed URL.
Pre-Signed URL: https://<namespace>.<endpoint>/<bucket>/<key>?AWSAccessKeyId=<access-id>01&Expires=1600801209&Signature=......../..................=
```

Debug logs for HTTP request show as follows (I will note that Signature param in presigned URL is now encoded and placed before other params, although that does not seem to matter when I extract the URL and send a GET request):

```
GET /<bucket>/VADRUserGuide.docx?Signature=........%2F..................%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=<access-id>&Expires=1600801209 HTTP/1.1
Host: <namespace>.<endpoint>
amz-sdk-invocation-id: ........-....-....-....-............
amz-sdk-retry: 3/152/440
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=access-id>/20200922/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;authorization;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=.................................................
User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/2.10.86 Windows_10/10.0 Java_HotSpot_TM__64-Bit_Server_VM/25.191-b12 Java/1.8.0_191 vendor/Oracle_Corporation io/async http/UNKNOWN
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
X-Amz-Date: 20200922T213232Z)
```

DownloadResource (source - https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/aws-reactive/src/main/java/com/baeldung/aws/reactive/s3/DownloadResource.java):

```
/**
 * @author Philippe
 *
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/inbox")
@Slf4j
public class DownloadResource {

    private final GeneratePresignedURL generatePresignedURL;
    private final S3AsyncClient s3client;
    private final S3ClientConfigurationProperties s3config;

    public DownloadResource(S3AsyncClient s3client, S3ClientConfigurationProperties s3config, GeneratePresignedURL generatePresignedURL) {
        this.s3client = s3client;
        this.s3config = s3config;
        this.generatePresignedURL = generatePresignedURL;
    }


    @GetMapping(path="/{filekey}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<ByteBuffer>>> downloadFile(@PathVariable("filekey") String filekey) {
        //generate pre-signed URL
        final String url = generatePresignedURL.getPresignedUrl(filekey);

        //extract signed URL params
        final String pattern = "(\\?|\\&)([^=]+)\\=([^&]+)";
        List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern)
                .matcher(url);
        while (m.find()) {
            params.add(m.group());
        }
        final String[] p0 = params.get(0).substring(1).split("=",2);
        final String[] p1 = params.get(1).substring(1).split("=",2);
        final String[] p2 = params.get(2).substring(1).split("=",2);

        //attach signed URL params via AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration
        AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration overrideConfiguration = AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                .putRawQueryParameter(p0[0], p0[1])
                .putRawQueryParameter(p1[0], p1[1])
                .putRawQueryParameter(p2[0], p2[1])
                .build();
        GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .key(filekey)
                .overrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
                .bucket(s3config.getBucket())
                .build();
        return Mono.fromFuture(s3client.getObject(request,new FluxResponseProvider()))
                .map( (response) -> {
                    checkResult(response.sdkResponse);
                    String filename = getMetadataItem(response.sdkResponse,"filename",filekey);

                    log.info("[I65] filename={}, length={}",filename, response.sdkResponse.contentLength() );

                    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, response.sdkResponse.contentType())
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(response.sdkResponse.contentLength()))
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"")
                            .body(response.flux);
                });
    }
    private void printRequestFields(GetObjectRequest request){
        System.out.println("request fields:");
        String[] parValues = new String[6];

        Field[] fields = request.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        //print field names paired with their values
        for ( Field field : fields  ) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                System.out.println( field.getName() +": ");
                //requires access to private field:
                System.out.println( field.get(request) );
            } catch ( IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lookup a metadata key in a case-insensitive way.
     * @param sdkResponse
     * @param key
     * @param defaultValue
     * @return
     */
    private String getMetadataItem(GetObjectResponse sdkResponse, String key, String defaultValue) {
        for( Entry<String, String> entry : sdkResponse.metadata().entrySet()) {
            if ( entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }


    // Helper used to check return codes from an API call
    private static void checkResult(GetObjectResponse response) {
        SdkHttpResponse sdkResponse = response.sdkHttpResponse();
        if ( sdkResponse != null && sdkResponse.isSuccessful()) {
            return;
        }

        throw new DownloadFailedException(response);
    }


    static class FluxResponseProvider implements AsyncResponseTransformer<GetObjectResponse,FluxResponse> {

        private FluxResponse response;

        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<FluxResponse> prepare() {
            response = new FluxResponse();
            return response.cf;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(GetObjectResponse sdkResponse) {
            this.response.sdkResponse = sdkResponse;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStream(SdkPublisher<ByteBuffer> publisher) {
            response.flux = Flux.from(publisher);
            response.cf.complete(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionOccurred(Throwable error) {
            response.cf.completeExceptionally(error);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Holds the API response and stream
     * @author Philippe
     */
    static class FluxResponse {

        final CompletableFuture<FluxResponse> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
        GetObjectResponse sdkResponse;
        Flux<ByteBuffer> flux;
    }

}
```

Configuration for S3AsyncClient (as you can see, credentials providers are commented out):

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(S3ClientConfigurationProperties.class)
public class S3ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public S3AsyncClient s3client(S3ClientConfigurationProperties s3props) {

        SdkAsyncHttpClient httpClient = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
                .writeTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
                .maxConcurrency(64)
                .build();

        S3Configuration serviceConfiguration = S3Configuration.builder()
                .checksumValidationEnabled(false)
                .chunkedEncodingEnabled(true)
                .build();

        S3AsyncClientBuilder b = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                .httpClient(httpClient)
                .region(s3props.getRegion())
// credentials provider commented out
                .serviceConfiguration(serviceConfiguration);

        if (s3props.getEndpoint() != null) {
            b = b.endpointOverride(s3props.getEndpoint());
        }

        return b.build();
    }


// credentials provider Bean commented out


}
```

Client for regular AmazonS3 client (used for GeneratePresignedUrlRequest):

```
@Configuration
public class S3Configuration {

    @Bean
    public S3Storage s3Storage(S3ServiceInfo s3ServiceInfo) {
        final ClientConfiguration httpsClientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS).withSignerOverride("S3SignerType");
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
        httpsClientConfig.getApacheHttpClientConfig().setSslSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext));

        AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
            .withClientConfiguration(httpsClientConfig)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(s3ServiceInfo.getAccessKey(), s3ServiceInfo.getSecretKey())))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endpointUrlWithNamespace(s3ServiceInfo.getEndpoint(), s3ServiceInfo.getAccessKey()), null))
            .build();

        return new S3Storage(client, s3ServiceInfo.getBucket(), s3ServiceInfo.getEndpoint());
    }

    protected String endpointUrlWithNamespace(String endpoint, String accessKey) {
        //extract namespace from access-key (verify format)
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("((.+?-){3}ns\\d\\d)-").matcher(accessKey);
        if (!matcher.find()) return endpoint;
        String namespace = matcher.group(1);

        return endpoint.contains("://s3") ? endpoint.replace("://", "://" + namespace + ".") : endpoint;
    }


    @Configuration
    public class S3LocalConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public S3ServiceInfo s3ServiceInfo(
                @Value("${s3.accessKey}") String accessKey,
                @Value("${s3.secretKey}") String secretKey,
                @Value("${s3.bucket}") String bucket,
                @Value("${s3.endpoint}") String endpoint) {

            return new S3ServiceInfo(null, accessKey, secretKey, endpoint, bucket);
        }
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class S3Storage {
        private AmazonS3 client;
        private String bucket;
        private String endpoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the S3AsyncClient to download the file? The url contains everything, you can use any non-aws-specific tool to download it

Comment: @TamásSallai, good question- I am able to download it with WebClient as a InputStreamSource, but am not sure that this is the best practice and wanted to be able to download it with the Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<ByteBuffer>>> type.